# Python getting all links from a google search result page

Tags: python, url, hyperlink

i want to create a script that returns all the urls found in a page a google for example , so i create this script : (using BeautifulSoup)

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print link["href"]
```

and it return this 403 forbidden result :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\sql\sql.py", line 3, in <module>
    page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

any idea to avoid this error or another methode to get the urls from of the search result ?

Comment: You probably need to se a user agent so it thinks your a web browser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No problem using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
links = soup.findAll("a")
```

Some of the links have links are like  `search%:http://` where the end of one joins another so we need to split then using re

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
import re
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=",""))

['https://www.see.asso.fr/&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNF2_I8jB98JwR3jcKniLZekSrRO7Q']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:f7M8NX1XmDsJ', 'https://www.see.asso.fr/%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBUQIDAA&usg=AFQjCNF8WJButjMNXQXvXBbtyXnF1SgiOg']
['https://www.see.asso.fr/3ei&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBgQ0gIoADAA&usg=AFQjCNGnPL1RiX5TekI_yMUc-w_f2oVXtw']
['https://www.see.asso.fr/node/9587&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBkQ0gIoATAA&usg=AFQjCNHX-6AzBgLQUF0s8TxFcZjIhxz_Hw']
['https://www.see.asso.fr/ree&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBoQ0gIoAjAA&usg=AFQjCNGkkd8e1JjiNrhSM4HQYE-M6g6j-w']
['https://www.see.asso.fr/node/130&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CBsQ0gIoAzAA&usg=AFQjCNEkVdpcbXDz5-cV9u2NNYoV6aM8VA']
['http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/see&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CB0QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNHQGwcsGpro26dhxFP6q-fQvwbB0Q']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:ooK-I_HuCkwJ', 'http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/see%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CCAQIDAB&usg=AFQjCNFRlV5Zv_n48Wivr4LeOkTQsA0D1Q']
['http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%25C3%25A9e&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CCMQFjAC&usg=AFQjCNGmtqmcXPqYZ_nwa0RWL0uYf5PMJw']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:GjcgkyzsUigJ', 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%2525C3%2525A9e%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CCYQIDAC&usg=AFQjCNHesOIBU3OXBspARcONbK_k_8-gnw']
['http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_S%25C3%25A9e&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CCkQFjAD&usg=AFQjCNGO-WIDl4TrBeo88WY9QsopWmsMyQ']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:izhQjC85nOoJ', 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camille_S%2525C3%2525A9e%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CCwQIDAD&usg=AFQjCNEfcIKsKbf026xgWT7NkrAueZvL0A']
['http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugersee&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDEQ9QEwBA&usg=AFQjCNHpfJW5-XdsgpFUSP-jEmHjXQUWHQ']
['http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Champex_See.jpg&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDMQ9QEwBQ&usg=AFQjCNEordFWr2QIaob45WlR5Yi-ZvZSiA']
['http://www.all-free-photos.com/show/showphotop.php%3Fidtop%3D4%26lang%3Dfr&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDUQ9QEwBg&usg=AFQjCNEC24FOIE5cvF4zmEDgq5-5xubM3w']
['http://www.allbestwallpapers.com/travel-zell_am_see,_kaprun,_austria_wallpapers.html&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDcQ9QEwBw&usg=AFQjCNFkzMZDuthZHvnF-JvyksNUqjt1dQ']
['http://www.see-swe.org/&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDkQFjAI&usg=AFQjCNF1zbcLfjanxgCXtHoOQXOdMgh_AQ']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:lzh6JxvKUTIJ', 'http://www.see-swe.org/%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CDwQIDAI&usg=AFQjCNFYN6tzzVaHsAc5aOvYNql3Zy4m3A']
['http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/see&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CD8QFjAJ&usg=AFQjCNFWYIGc1gj0prytowzqI-0LDFRvZA']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:G9v8lXWRCyQJ', 'http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/see%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CEIQIDAJ&usg=AFQjCNENzi4E1n-9qHYsNahY6lQzaW5Xvg']
['http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CEUQFjAK&usg=AFQjCNECGZjw-rBUALO43WaTh2yB9BUhDg']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:ywc4URuPdIQJ', 'http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CEgQIDAK&usg=AFQjCNE0pykIqXXRl08E-uTtoj03QEpnbg']
['http://see-concept.com/&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CEsQFjAL&usg=AFQjCNGFWjhiH7dEBhITJt01ob_JENlz1Q']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:jHTkOVEoRsAJ', 'http://see-concept.com/%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CE4QIDAL&usg=AFQjCNECPgxt9ZSFmZzK_ker9Hw_FoCi_A']
['http://www.theconjugator.com/la/conjugaison/du/verbe/see.html&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CFEQFjAM&usg=AFQjCNETCTQ0vPDIdV_2Q57qq11dyN0d8Q']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:xD7_Qo7roS8J', 'http://www.theconjugator.com/la/conjugaison/du/verbe/see.html%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CFQQIDAM&usg=AFQjCNF_hBCyDZncivYGnL7je5kYme9hEg']
['http://www.zellamsee-kaprun.com/fr&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CFcQFjAN&usg=AFQjCNFVDeBWrZMDSjK9jKYF4AQlIXa9lA']
['http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search%3Fq%3Dcache:BFBEUp05w7YJ', 'http://www.zellamsee-kaprun.com/fr%252Bsee%26hl%3Dfr%26%26ct%3Dclnk&sa=U&ei=ryv6U6PvEKzA7AaB4ICwCA&ved=0CFoQIDAN&usg=AFQjCNHtrOeEpYWqvT3f0M1p-gxUkYT1IA']
```

Comment: but it gives you just the google links , i want the links of sites in the search results

Comment: I only posted a snippet. Have you actually run the code?

Comment: houray ! ah that's correct but is there is a way to print only the url not that "/url?q=" 
++ avoid google links ? like a except filter or something ??

Comment: I will have a look in a bit when back on my comp

Comment: Ok , we are waiting for you ;) 
cause honestly i didn't try to handle such request i'm a noobie

Comment: It looks alright, but google wants me to accept Términos del Servicio first. How to handle this?

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is to use the google API (`pip install google`)
[GeeksforGeeks writes about it here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/)

```
from googlesearch import search   

# to search 
query = "see"

links = []
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2): 
    links.append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print link["href"]
```