# NameError: name 'requests' is not defined

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-import

I have taken this code as for help "[Python getting all links from a google search result page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471450/python-getting-all-links-from-a-google-search-result-page)" .

When I try importing requests in Python 3.3.3, I get `NameError: name 'requests' is not defined`. I tested the "request" and "bs4" module using the CMD prompt and both show that this library has been installed.

I am trying to extract the related searched links from Google Search Result, but I don't know why I'm getting this error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
import re
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print (re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
```

```
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/python/s/beauti.py", line 2, in <module>
    page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

Comment: If you never ran `import requests`, why would you expect the name `requests` to mean anything? (Given that it's not given in https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html, which is where the very limited set of builtins are listed).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

install `requests`

```
pip install requests
```

and change your code like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content) 
links = soup.findAll("a") 
for link in links: 
    if link['href'].startswith('/url?q='): 
        print (link['href'].replace('/url?q=',''))
```

Comment: is pip install requests also library?

Comment: i have placed in this way: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print (re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))

Comment: no,pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python

Comment: i have written in this way but nt giving me links, so i have to install pip?

Comment: you must first install `pip`, and install `requests` via pip

Comment: ok.i think u are saying this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests i have installed this one through cmd. wts pip now ?

Comment: How did you install it without `pip`?

Comment: if you install requests, just import it. pip is a tools for installing python package.

Comment: i followed this way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4 and installed that "requests-2.4.3.tar.gz" is that u are saying request. did i install correctly?

Comment: go to python shell and run `import requests`

Comment: written and after pressing enter shows ">>>" as means next line

Comment: i have written in this way: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.google.dz/search?q=see")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print (re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))

Comment: requests already installed. you can use it in your code . just import it in your code by `import requests`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64814/discussion-between-user3440716-and-hasan-ramezani).