# Python Scraping links from search results

Tags: php, python, search, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to generate/retrieve a list of news links from a keyword search from a news website using Python. For Google search, I know some use 
[requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471450/python-getting-all-links-from-a-google-search-result-page), but while Google search page has its own link address (i.e. https://www.google.dz/search?q=keyword), some websites do not transfer keyword through web address.

First - for example, in http://english.hani.co.kr/ , users are led to a search result page http://search.hani.co.kr/Search with list of links regardless which keyword they type ([Korea Times](http://www.koreatimes.co.kr/www/archive/ksearch.asp) is another example). In this way, is it still possible to use Python library to extract those links?

Second - in the earlier two and many other cases (like [this](http://sitesearch.asahi.com/.cgi/sitesearch/sitesearch.pl?Keywords=python)), the search results are displayed in as many as hundreds of pages. What tools and techniques should I turn to in order to produce a comprehensive list of news links?

Comment: (1) why do you ask how to get the search query from a SERP? (you don't need it; if you make the requests yourself) Where do you get the SERP content from?  (2) Limit your questions to a single issue per question: how to get paginated results is a different question.

Comment: Hey! (1) because if I want to scrape all the link, I need to feed specific pages to BeautifulSoup instead of the general url (http://search.hani.co.kr/Search), which only gives me the search homepage instead of any particular results even if I make the request myself. For (2), thanks for the note!

Answer (score 2):

> There are two basic tasks that are used to scrape web sites:
>
> - Load a web page to a string.
> - Parse HTML from a web page to locate the interesting bits.

You can see more details how to do [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python).

So, some searchs engine use **GET** to do a search and others the method **POST**. For those that use method POST the unique way is doing the search (not by url) and get the html results for analyze.

Both ways(GET and POST) you can use **beautifulsoup**.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Do you know which place should I look for specifics about getting html result through POST? The link is a good read but I would like to read more into this.