# Get links from search engines using python

Tags: python, search

Supose I have a query : "Games and work"
I want to make a script to search that query in google and return all links displayed when the query is being searched in google.
Of course there will be thousands of results,  I just want first four pages.

I already searched some modules but they don't do what I want.
https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API

I want to get all links from a search.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471450/python-getting-all-links-from-a-google-search-result-page should help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *Google Custom Search*. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).

A similar service exists for Microsft's Bing, information can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/).

Also, note that these services offer a lot more than what you are requesting (searching only "part of the web" etc.)